# Prove there exists at least $n$ zeros of $f$ in the open interval $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $f\in [a,b]$, and $\int_a^b f(x)x^k\,dx=0$, $\quad k=0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $n-1$. Show that **there exists at least $n$ zeros of $f$ in the open interval $(a,b)$**.

I know that if $n=1$, it is nothing but integral mean value theorem.

Comment: Do you miss some condition on $f$? At least it should be continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f$ has at most $n-1$ zeros. That means $f$ has isolated zeros.

Then we consider the zeros where $f$ change signs, i.e, all the points $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, $f(x_0-\epsilon)f(x_0+\epsilon)<0$ for any sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. The number of those points are at most $n-1$. We assume the points are $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m$, $m\leq n-1$.

Then we can consider $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)d x$, where $g(x)=(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_m)$. By assumption $\int_a^b f(x)x^k=0$, we have $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=0$.

On the other hand, since $f$ only change signs on $x_i$, we know that $f(x)g(x)\geq 0$ always holds, or   $f(x)g(x)\leq 0$ always holds.

This implies that $f=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is kind of you to provde me with the answer.